# Headless task in react native android appliation

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am currently using the headless task to receive a push notification and show the local notification. I am currently using react-native-firebase to integrate firebase cloud messaging.

```
export default bgMessaging = (message) => {
    console.log('hello', message)
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

This is the piece of code which I am using to create task.

And in index.js

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

I am using this to registerHeadlessTask.

But when the app is in the killed state I am not getting any console message and don't if my task is running.

Need help to know how can I debug the background task and show custom notification for the killed state.

Comment: I wonder you don't need to use HeadlessTask. React Native Firebase has another API (Notification) that always get messages while the application is running in the background. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/introduction

Comment: Not exactly sure, I want to customize the remote notification and could only this way. But since I wasn't not receiving any handler here. I want to debug this in detail.

Comment: @cauchy do you found any solutions for debugging headless js task or do you got working with background task

Comment: I am trying to play sounds through it, but doesn't seems to be working. Did you found any solution.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it as follows:

// index.js

```
import { AppRegistry, Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

//receive the message in the background
messaging().onMessage(async teste => {
  console.log('teste:', teste);

  const novo = (title, message) => {
    return Alert.alert(title, message);
  };
  novo(teste.notification.title, teste.notification.body);
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

This is because we have to validate when the push message arrives in the background in the app